# How to fire click event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in jQuery programming. I am trying to fire a click event on list click, but it is not working properly. The following is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">

<link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css" />
$("ul#select li").click(function(e){
    //targ = $(e.target);
    if($(this).hasClass("selected"))
    {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
        document.location= "cambridge:clearanswer";
    }
    else
    {
        currentanswer = $(this).html();
        document.location = "cambridge:checkanswer:"+currentanswer;
        $("ul.select li").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
});

function getUsed()
{
    var total = "";
    $(".boxWord.boxWordUsed").each(function (i){ total = total + this.getAttribute('index_no') + ":"; });
    return total;
}

</script>
</script>
<link href="style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="question" >
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b" class="select" id="select"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider" class="selected">Overview</li> 
<li data-role="list-divider" class="selected">Overview</li> 
</ul>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are not writing codes in `<script>` tag and the code messed up between multiple tags. Then you have use `$(document).ready()`. You also have other errors in code, I have corrected all of them for you, I understand you are a newbie :).

**See a working demo here** http://jsfiddle.net/DtHJY/1/

Here is the corrected code:

```
 <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("ul#select li").click(function(e){
    alert('test');
                        //targ = $(e.target);
                        if($(this).hasClass("selected"))
                        {
                        $(this).removeClass("selected");
                        document.location= "cambridge:clearanswer";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        currentanswer = $(this).html();
                        document.location = "cambridge:checkanswer:"+currentanswer;
                        $("ul.select li").removeClass("selected");
                        $(this).addClass("selected");
                        }
                        });




function getUsed()
{
    var total = "";
    $(".boxWord.boxWordUsed").each(function (i){ total = total + this.getAttribute('index_no') + ":"; });
    return total;
}

    });
</script>
<link href="style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="question" >
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b" class="select" id="select">
            <li data-role="list-divider" class="selected">Overview</li>
<li data-role="list-divider" class="selected">Overview</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello bro Nice answer bro but I have no guidance I have to make an application for android I have to use Jquery can you guide me to learn it

Comment: Sure, just post question if you have any problem :)

Comment: hey bro it is not working in my browser my browser is giving two errors Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
jquery.jsFailed to load resource

Comment: Keep your jQuery file (jquery.js) at the same path where HTML is. You can download jQuery from http://jquery.com

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your script up in document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   ...your click event code
});
```

Otherwise it may try to attach the event before the element is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
document.location.href = 'link'
```

instead

and also do not forgot to wrap your code into

```
$(function(){
     //your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have wrapped the event binder in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` then it will work perfectly.

Have a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E5BZ9/